# AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'outbound_layers'

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to get the outbound nodes of a layer in keras:
Firs, I got the inbound layers in this way:

```py
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')

f_tmp=open("ResNet50_inbound_nodes.h", "w+")
for layer in model.layers:
    for int_node in layer._inbound_nodes:
        for inbound_l in int_node.inbound_layers:
            f_tmp.write("\n\tin bound layer name: %s" % (inbound_l.name))
        f_tmp.write("\n\n")
```

I tried to get the out bound nodes the same way:

```py
for out_node in layer._outbound_nodes:
    for outbound_l in out_node.outbound_layers:
        f_tmp.write("\n\toutbound layer name: %s" % (outbound_l.name))
    f_tmp.write("\n\n")
```

but it gives me an error that I cannot solve:
**"AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'outbound_layers'"**

Is there a way in keras to get the outbound layers of a layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error message says `Node` does not have "outbound_layers", It has [`outbound_layer`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L1308).

Hence slight modification in your code.

```
for out_node in layer._outbound_nodes:
    print(out_node.outbound_layer.name)
# bn4e_branch2a
# activation_84
# res4e_branch2b
# ...
```